# Downloading files with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, download

I'm writing a web app using CakePDF and I'm having difficulty downloading files. It looks easy enough according to the docs (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files), and my code is really just a copy-and-paste job:

```
public function download($request_id) {
    $filename = $this->getFilename($request_id);
    $file = $this->Attachment->getFile($filename);
    $this->response->file($file['path']);
    return $this->response; 
}
```

Unfortunately this is throwing an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getFile() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\quickanalyses\app\Controller\DocumentController.php on line 7
```

I've looked through the docs but it doesn't say that you need to do anything to get the Attachment reference, so I can't work out why its failing. I've also tried `var $uses = array('Attachment')`, `var $components = array('Attachment')` and `var $helpers = array('Attachment')` in the controller but nothing is helping

Answer (score 0):

Feeling very stupid now. I didn't download the latest version of cake, instead modified an old project, and so I'm using 2.1.0 instead of 2.3, meaning I need to use media views instead